# How to incrementally train an nltk classifier

Tags: python, nltk

I am working on a project to classify snippets of text using the python nltk module and the naivebayes classifier.  I am able to train on corpus data and classify another set of data but would like to feed additional training information into the classifier after initial training.

If I'm not mistaken, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this, in that the NaiveBayesClassifier.train method takes a complete set of training data.  Is there a way to add to the the training data without feeding in the original featureset?

I'm open to suggestions including other classifiers that can accept new training data over time.

Comment: Did you finally found a solution for this problem?

Comment: I hacked around the classifier internals a bit to supply new training data without retraining. It was a long time ago now, so I can't recall exactly, but I think it was feasible. I didn't get far with the project after that, so it's not in active service.

Answer (score 8):

There's 2 options that I know of:

1) Periodically retrain the classifier on the new data. You'd accumulate new training data in a corpus (that already contains the original training data), then every few hours, retrain & reload the classifier. This is probably the simplest solution.

2) Externalize the internal model, then update it manually. The `NaiveBayesClassifier` can be created directly by giving it a `label_prodist` and a `feature_probdist`. You could create these separately, pass them in to a `NaiveBayesClassifier`, then update them whenever new data comes in. The classifier would use this new data immediately. You'd have to look at the `train` method for details on how to update the probability distributions.

Comment: Thanks Jacob!  I'm hoping to avoid option 1 as I suspect there might be performance issues (I'm going to have a lot of separate classifiers).  I'll look into option 2, it might also help with persisting classifier (or it's knowledge at least), and pickling the whole thing produces a pretty big file (again, considering scalability).

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice a little speed for the sake of horizontal scalability, you could persist the models in Redis by creating a ProbDistI subclass that uses a Redis Hash for storage/lookup. Then you don't have to do any pickling, and the classifier is "always on".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm looking at some memcached + database options too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning NLTK, so please correct me if I'm wrong. This is using the Python 3 branch of NLTK, which might be incompatible.

There is an `update()` method to the `NaiveBayesClassifier` instance, which appears to add to the training data:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier

train = [
    ('training test totally tubular', 't'),
]

cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
cl.update([('super speeding special sport', 's')])

print('t', cl.classify('tubular test'))
print('s', cl.classify('super special'))
```

This prints out:

```
t t
s s
```

Comment: do note that textblob don't really "update" the model by adjusting the probabilities but it retrains a new model.

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob said, the second method is the right way
And hopefully someone write a code

Look

https://baali.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/incrementally-training-nltk-classifier/